# Eclipse Tomcat - Context environment variable

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven

I use eclipse + tomcat + maven.

When I deploy my project to Tomcat, the following entry gets added to the server.xml of the tomcat configuration:

```
<Context docBase="C:\ws_eclipse\ws\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\MyApp" path="/myApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyApp"/>
```

What I actually want is to add an environment variable so that the context looks like this:

```
  <Context docBase="C:\ws_eclipse\ws\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\MyApp" path="/myApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyApp">
       <Environment name="config.file" type="java.lang.String" value="C:/test/config.xml" /> 
</Context>
```

I tried adding it as an environment variable in eclipse run configuration, but when I deployed the application on tomcat, the context does not include the environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a *context.xml* file in the *META-INF* directory of your webapp. The content of this file may look like:

```
<Context>
  <Parameter name="config.file" value="C:/test/config.xml"/>
</Context>
```

This has the same effect as defining a `<context-param/>` in your web.xml. Use `ServletContext.getInitParameter("config.file")` to retrieve it's value as a String.

You may use `Environment` as well, but it's probably overkill (You just need a String anyway, I think).

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Ohh, thanks. I added the Env entry in the context.xml as you specified and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Nice. The biggest benefit of using such a file is that you don't need to change the server.xml file, because of data which is relevant to a given webapp only. If possible one should use a context.xml (this is practice as advocated by the tomcat devs). Anyway, glad to hear things worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Setting it in application launch configuration is the best way, you might want to verify what you did at here - [Creating a Java application launch configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm)

HTH

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I tried adding it as a JVM argument as well as an environment variable. But, it does not get added to the Context in Tomcat.